# Sharing util modules between actively developed apps

Tags: python

We have a growing library of apps depending on a set of common util modules.  We'd like to:

1. share the same utils codebase between all projects
2. allow utils to be extended (and fixed!) by developers working on any project
3. have this be reasonably simple to use for devs (i.e. not a big disruption to workflow)
4. cross-platform (no diffs for devs on Macs/Win/Linux)

We currently do this "manually", with the utils versioned as part of each app.  This has its benefits, but is also quite painful to repeatedly fix bugs across a growing number of codebases.

On the plus side, it's very simple to deal with in terms of workflow - util module is part of each app, so on that side there is zero overhead.

We also considered (fleetingly) using filesystem links or some such (not portable between OS's)

I understand the implications about release testing and breakage, etc.  These are less of a problem than the mismatched utils are at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of Python paths (the paths searched when looking for module to import).

Thus you can create **different directory for utils** and include it within different repository than the project that use these utils. Then include path to this repository in `PYTHONPATH`.

This way if you write `import mymodule`, it will eventually find `mymodule` in the directory containing utils. So, basically, **it will work similarly as it works for standard Python modules**.

This way you will have **one repository for utils (or separate for each util, if you wish), and separate repositories for other projects**, **regardless of the version control system you use**.

Answer (score 1):

What versioning system are you under? If you are under **git**, take a look to [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html). The idea in this case is that you would be able to keep a unique, separate repository with the utils, that would be polled into the various project automatically.

I have no direct experience with **mercurial**, but I believe [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos) are the equivalent feature.

If you are under SVN... wait... I hope not! :)